# How to make a Batch file, that puts another batch file to a destination folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a Batch File that puts file.bat to C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop .
I had referred [THIS TUTORIAL](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-Batch-files-Install-any-file/) but this didn't help for my batch file. 
I would like anyone to tell me the code to make it happen...
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `copy "file.bat" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this, using either copy or xcopy
for example, as said in comments:

```
copy "file.bat" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\"
```

But you need to have a specific question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

> Type ">" without quotes, that means overwrite, but if this: >> it means add data to file
>
> Note that you can add as many lines as you want, but keep in mind about these signs ">" and ">>"

```
@echo off
cls
pause
cls
echo (Your text here)>>C:\Users\%username%\Desktop.
```

I tried that once in my game and then it worked for me.

Hope this helps!